# aws s3 sync NOT sending my files to my bucket AWS S3 (Circleci)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, circleci-2.0

I'm using Circleci to deploy my project on my AWS S3 bucket.

After many attempts I was able to finally made my config.yml work and according to Circleci interface everything is running succefully.

[image]

The problem is that when I access my bucket there's nothing there.

I already tried this:

```
- 
        run: 
          command: "aws s3 sync myAppPath s3://myBucketName"
```

Anyone could help? I have no errors and everything is done successully but no file on my bucket.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please update with any logs or error messages? Also, can you verify that your awscli creds are setup per the [documentation]?(https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-amazon-s3/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add credentials. 
add environmental variables in the project https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/

screen:
[image]

And then configure config .circleci/config.yml :

```
# deploy to aws s3
  deploy:
    docker: 
      - image: cibuilds/aws:1.15.73
    environment:
      aws_access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      aws_secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    steps:
      - attach_workspace:
          at: ./workspace
      - run: 
          name: Deploy to S3 if tests pass and branch is develop
          command: aws s3 sync workspace/public s3://your.bucket/ --delete
```

also just let you know to debug aws cli use circleci cli:

[image]

And in your terminal, once you connect by ssh to circleci
[image]

try:

```
aws s3 sync workspace/public s3://your.bucket/ --debug
```